# List view and toolbar are cutting down

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I have an app, which has in main activity expandable list view and toolbar. Each row of expandable list view has a editText, which appears on a click on a textView. But if editText appears on a bottom of the screen and you tapping on it, popuping keyboard cutting off top of the screen, which includes toolbar and part of expandable list. As I understood, problem in keyboard. How to fix this?

[Video with a problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jkPFCwayNj6BVRii2pUQGagkhrES-2fz/view?usp=sharing/)

row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/changeRowLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/country_name_change"
        android:layout_width="168dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:text="Country name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/days_count_change"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/input"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:clickable="true"
        tools:text="666"
        android:focusable="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="116dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:text="666" />
```

mainacitivty

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/custom_toolbar"/>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">

    </ExpandableListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your activity is panning when the keyboard pops up. You can either use adjustResize or the adjustNothing inside your activity declaration in your manifest if you don't want this behaviour. add this line

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Comment: It's works, but partially. I had in my manifest "adjustPan", because I had a problem with edittext (it recreated listview infitinly). When I setting up "adjustResize" problem is fixing, but I'm losing focus on editText when I'm clicking on it (if editText was in bottom of the screen). Maybe you know how to set focus after click in edittext with solution which you told?

Comment: can you make a video of the problem

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E7jBVvWG4vQqCRq92GvdMDfNGSmT1dEA/view?usp=sharing

It's with adjustResize. With adjustNothing i'm losing focus on editText and it's goes under my keyboard. With adjustPin I have a problem, which I wrote in this post